# How to differentiate from different hex files of different families of microcontrollers?

Tags: decompilation, c, hex

Is there any way to differentiate different microcontroller's hex files? I have a hex file and now I have forgotten of which micro-controller it belongs. Is there any available tool to tell this? or any tip or trick to know?

**Edit:**
There is a similar question [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/233/what-pic-processor-was-this-hex-file-meant-for), But this question specifically belongs to PIC family while I what if we have to differentiate from different families like AVR, 8051, PIC etc.

Comment: Related: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/233/187

Comment: Perhaps you could specify the microcontroller brand already? ARM, PIC, ..?

Comment: I have edited my question, making it more clarifying

Comment: Maybe someone could contribute common byte patterns you're likely to see for different architectures? Is that the question you're asking?

Answer (score 6):

My first idea would be to perform a frequency analysis on aligned bytes. For most of the assembly languages, the most relevant bytes are aligned on the most significant bits.

So it might be quite easy to create a distinguer that can recognize the type of asm. But, suprisingly, after a few googling, I didn't find any tool or paper about this...

Maybe there is something to do here.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of tools designed for this. In practise, loading it into IDA (or any other disassembler) with different architectures until it looks right is probably the easiest way to do it. You might be able to write a script to automate this.

If you want to build your own tool, I suggest you look at [Christopher Domas's talk "The future of RE Dynamic Binary Visualization"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4bM3Gut1hIk). It discusses a number of techniques that can be used to analyse unknown data. The general idea graph the frequency of every group of two or three bytes in each file. The graphs are distinctly different between different architectures, and could be used to automatically identify data types. The actual tool, and the dataset you would need, is not publicly available, but this is the way I would go if I wanted to do automatic architecture detection.

A simpler approach would be to search for function prologue patterns in different architectures. Although the implementation is simpler, it would take more human-time to prepare the dataset (because identifying function prologues cannot be automated). Some processors may not be powerful enough to run C code, and if the code is not compiled it's possible to not have predictable function prologues. You may be able to find other common operations that you could search for.

Comment: My first thought was Domas's Cantor Dust tool as well, but I can't seem to find the demo version online anywhere. Absent that, a simple histogram of 2 or 3 bytes sequences in the file can give a quick picture of what kind of data is in it and lead to some common instructions.  Some hex editors have histogram functionality built in if you don't want to write up your own tool.

Comment: @nopnopgoose a 'demo/alpha' version of Cantor Dust can be downloaded from the [black hat media archives](https://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-12/Arsenal/Domas/_cantor.dust_.7z.zip). If you rename your binary to "visual_re.example" under /resources/ you can play around with it a bit.

Answer (score -2):

Try to get an idea of what kinds of CPUs it could target. You can probably also guess the bit length of the CPU by looking at this file (file_size % 32 == 0? Probably 32 bit). Once you have a simple list, run the binary through some disassemblers and see if the code makes sense. Try running it in some emulated CPUs and see if it does anything.

Also, keep in mind that invalid instructions might not mean you've got the wrong CPU, it could just be data or something. It's actually probably worth checking out the file to see if you can't find any strings or anything, just to get a better sense of where things are.

Comment: We're talking about microcontrollers here, there are 8-bit and 16-bit MCUs as well. This is _not_ about a computer.

Comment: Oh, whoops, misread the question. Apologies.